# non interactive shell locale

Tags: ssh, shell, localization

I'm running commands on a remote host via `ssh` where i'd like to have locale vars set. I do not care about the full profile scripts from a true interactive shell, just the locale vars.

The minimum test is to have `ssh remotehost locale` to output something other than "POSIX" or empty values.

I already tried to set `SendEnv LANG` on my ssh config. But that did not work.

The only workaround that does work is to manually export the locale to a hardcoded value each time i run a command. e.g. `ssh vma LANG=en_US.utf-8 locale` or more realistically `ssh vma export LANG=en_US.utf-8; series; of; commands;`

default shell is bash but i'm guessing a possible solution would be on the ssh side alone?

Comment: `SendEnv` is the correct approach. Is `AcceptEnv` on the sshd configured to accept your vars?

Comment: sigh. no. I tested with TERM to see if it was needed, but TERM apparently is whitelisted regardless. Now that i added `AcceptEnv LANG LC_COLLATE` to my `sshd_config` file it works fine!